# Preventing rendered image from 'flickering' when updating in java?

Tags: java, game-engine

I have the following code:

```
public class Screen {
...// more code
private int width, height;
public int[] pixels;

public void render(int xOffSet, int yOffSet) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        int yPix = y + yOffSet;
        if (yPix < 0 || yPix >= height)
            continue;
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            int xPix = x + xOffSet;
            if (xPix < 0 || xPix >= width)
                continue;
            pixels[(xPix) + (yPix) * width] = Sprite.grass.pixels[(x & Sprite.grass.SIZE - 1)
                    + (y & Sprite.grass.SIZE - 1) * Sprite.grass.SIZE];
        }
    }
}
```

Which basically renders many of the same 16x16 tile in the screen.

Then I have these two methods (looping in a thread)

```java
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    ...//more code

    public void run() {
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final double ns = 1000000000.0 / 60.0; // Nanosegundos necesarios para
                                                // correr el juego a 60fps
        double delta = 0;
        int frames = 0;
        int updates = 0;

        while (running) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while (delta >= 1) {
                tick();
                updates++;
                delta--;
            }
            render();
            frames++;

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                timer += 1000;
                frame.setTitle(title + "\t \t FPS: " + frames + " UPS: " + updates + ".");
                frames = updates = 0;
            }
        }
        stop();
    }

    public int x = 0, y = 0;

    public void tick() {
        keyboard.tick();
        if(keyboard.up) y--;
        if(keyboard.down) y++;
        if(keyboard.left) x--;
        if(keyboard.right) x++;
    }

    public void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        screen.clear();

        screen.render(x, y);

        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
            pixels[i] = screen.pixels[i];
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }
}
```

Updating and re-rendering the screen.

My problem is that when I press any key, to move the screen, it looks like the image is 'flickering', not updating at once (the game is running at around 1000 fps and 60 ticks per second). Is there any simple way to fix this?

Comment: Use [*Double Buffering and Page Flipping*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/doublebuf.html).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I am using triple buffering (added that part, under the class game), I thought that was supposed to prevent my issue. Is double buffering better?

Comment: If you see flicker then you aren't drawing on sync.

Comment: `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);` - could you add the code that declares and updates `image`?